# How to define a generic function in Rust which accepts a generic function with a trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write a function which accepts a generic function as an argument.
The argument (`processor` below) should have a trait bound on its argument.

```
    fn process<P, T>(processor: &P)
    where
        P: Fn(&T),
        T: ToString,
    {
        processor("foo");
    }
    
    fn processor<T>(x: &T)
    where
        T: ToString,
    {
        println!("{}", x.to_string());
    }
    
    fn main() {
        process(&processor);
    }
```

This gives the following errors. How can I fix the code?

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:15
  |
1 | fn process<P, T>(processor: &P)
  |               - this type parameter
...
6 |     processor("foo");
  |     --------- ^^^^^ expected `&T`, found `&str`
  |     |
  |     arguments to this function are incorrect
  |
  = note: expected reference `&T`
             found reference `&'static str`
note: callable defined here
 --> src/main.rs:3:8
  |
3 |     P: Fn(&T),
  |        ^^^^^^

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:17:14
   |
17 |     process(&processor);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the function `processor`
   |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
17 |     process(&processor::<T>);
   |                       +++++
```

Comment: You've parameterised your `process` function by `T` but yet always pass the invoked `processor` an argument of type `&str`.  Consider https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96e869f38908c78038736a41b3d72bd8 ?

Comment: To be clear, function parameters are reified at callsite.  So `T` is determined by the caller and `process` cannot then choose for it to be `&str` as the caller might have selected something else.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

As a close alternative, you can define a trait:

```rust
trait Processor {
    fn process<T: ToString + ?Sized>(&self, v: &T);
}

fn process<P>(processor: &P)
where
    P: Processor,
{
    processor.process("foo");
}

struct MyProcessor;
impl Processor for MyProcessor {
    fn process<T: ToString + ?Sized>(&self, x: &T) {
        println!("{}", x.to_string());
    }
}

fn main() {
    process(&MyProcessor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another trait bound on `&'static str` so that you can convert it to `T` before passing it to your callback:

```
fn process<P, T>(processor: &P)
where
    P: Fn(&T),
    T: ToString,
    &'static str: Into<T>,
{
    processor(&"foo".into());
}

fn processor<T>(x: &T)
where
    T: ToString,
{
    println!("{}", x.to_string());
}

fn main() {
    process(&processor::<&str>);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3be64164031d83f39ed543186e2f4b4)